# Flutter missed permission? what is permission name?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, android-camera

I had an app with flutter. the log bellow, I saw error is miss permission but I didn't find it. Do you know it? please help me. I registered `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in androidMainifest.xml file.

`/zygote64(28918): Do partial code cache collection, code=60KB, data=45KB I/zygote64(28918): After code cache collection, code=60KB, data=45KB I/zygote64(28918): Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB E/libc    (28918): Access denied finding property "persist.camera.cfa.packagelist" W/data_extraction(28918): type=1400 audit(0.0:204): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=6716 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:camera_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 ppid=3602 pcomm="main" pgid=3602 pgcomm="main"`

Comment: I have same issue, have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

did you use the device camera?

try add this to your AndroidManifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`

Comment: no success for me :( when I open camera on device it will be `Access denied finding property "persist.camera.cfa.packagelist"` . But I still capture image

Comment: have you run `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` after adding that permission?

Comment: @denis is my solution helped you?